# Linker warning after builds with CodevisionAVR for ATmega16a

Tags: c, build, warnings, avr, atmega

this code is c language and should be builds for **ATmega16a**
I use **Codevision** to build it but I have this warning but I cant find why. I tried different way to test that but I still give this warning.
what should I do ?

> Linker warning: function 'UserIdentify' not used in data stack usage
> calculation due to possible recursive calls

```
void main(void)
{
    DDRC = 0x07;
    DDRD = 0x78;
    PORTD = 0x07;

    lcd_init(20);

    if (UL == -1)
    {
        UL = 1;
        user[0].role = true;
        user[0].username = 123;
        user[0].password = 321;
    }

    while (1)
    {
        UserIdentify();
    }
}

void UserIdentify(void)
{
    username = 0;
    password = 0;
    checker = true;
    lcd_clear();
    lcd_putsf("Welcome");
    lcd_gotoxy(0, 1);
    lcd_putsf("Login press 1");
    lcd_gotoxy(0, 2);
    lcd_putsf("Register press 2");
    lcd_gotoxy(0, 3);
    lcd_putsf("About this device 3");

    switch (ScanKey())
    {
    case 1:
        lcd_clear();
        lcd_putsf("Enter Username : ");
        lcd_gotoxy(0, 1);
        username = ScanKey();
        lcd_gotoxy(0, 2);
        lcd_putsf("Enter Password : ");
        lcd_gotoxy(0, 3);
        password = ScanKey();

        for (i = 0; i < UL; i++)
        {
            if (user[i].username == username)
            {
                if (user[i].password == password)
                {
                    PORTC .0 = 1;
                    lcd_clear();
                    lcd_putsf("You Entered !!");
                    delay_ms(150);
                    PORTC .0 = 0;
                    if (user[i].role == false)
                    {
                        UserPannel(i);
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (user[i].role == true)
                    {
                        AdminPannel(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (checker)
        {
            PORTC .1 = 1;
            lcd_clear();
            lcd_putsf("Wrong User or Pass !");
            delay_ms(150);
            PORTC .1 = 0;
        }
        break;

    case 2:
        EditUser(5, -1);
        UserPannel(UL - 1);
        break;

    case 3:
        EditUser(8, -1);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

void EditUser(int Case, int Code)
{
    switch (Case)
    {
    case 1:
        lcd_clear();
        lcd_putsf("Enter new Username:");
        lcd_gotoxy(0, 1);
        user[Code].username = ScanKey();
        lcd_gotoxy(0, 2);
        PORTC .0 = 1;
        lcd_putsf("Username changed.");
        delay_ms(150);
        PORTC .0 = 0;
        break;

    case 2:
        lcd_clear();
        lcd_putsf("Enter new Password:");
        lcd_gotoxy(0, 1);
        user[Code].password = ScanKey();
        lcd_gotoxy(0, 1);
        PORTC .0 = 1;
        lcd_putsf("Password changed.");
        delay_ms(150);
        PORTC .0 = 0;
        break;

    case 3:
        lcd_clear();
        for (i = Code; i < UL; i++)
        {
            user[Code] = user[Code + 1];
        }
        UL--;
        PORTC .0 = 1;
        lcd_putsf("User Deleted.");
        delay_ms(150);
        PORTC .0 = 0;
        UserIdentify();
        break;

    case 4:
        checker = false;
        break;

    case 5:
        if (UL != 10)
        {
            do
            {
                lcd_clear();
                lcd_putsf("Enter Username :");
                lcd_gotoxy(0, 1);
                user[UL].username = ScanKey();

                lcd_gotoxy(0, 2);
                lcd_putsf("Enter Password :");
                lcd_gotoxy(0, 3);
                user[UL].password = ScanKey();
            } while (user[UL].username == 0 || user[UL].password == 0);

            lcd_clear();
            if (user[Code].role == true)
            {
                lcd_putsf("Promote to admin ? ");
                lcd_gotoxy(0, 1);
                lcd_putsf("Yes press 1");
                lcd_gotoxy(0, 2);
                lcd_putsf("No press 2");
                if (ScanKey() == 1)
                {
                    user[UL].role = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    user[UL].role = false;
                }
                lcd_gotoxy(0, 3);
            }
            UL++;
            PORTC .0 = 1;
            lcd_putsf("User added !!");
            delay_ms(150);
            PORTC .0 = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            PORTC .1 = 1;
            lcd_clear();
            lcd_putsf("Users full !!");
            delay_ms(150);
            PORTC .1 = 0;
        }

        break;

    case 6:
        if (user[Code].role == true)
        {
            lcd_clear();
            lcd_putsf("Promote to admin ?");
            lcd_gotoxy(0, 1);
            lcd_putsf("Yes press 1");
            lcd_gotoxy(0, 2);
            lcd_putsf("No press 2");
            if (ScanKey() == 1)
            {
                PORTC .0 = 1;
                user[Code].role = true;
                lcd_gotoxy(0, 3);
                lcd_putsf("Promoted !");
                delay_ms(150);
                PORTC .0 = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                PORTC .1 = 1;
                lcd_gotoxy(0, 3);
                lcd_putsf("Cancelled !");
                delay_ms(150);
                PORTC .1 = 0;
            }
        }
        break;

    case 7:
        if (user[Code].role == true)
        {
            lcd_clear();
            lcd_putsf("Demote admin ?");
            lcd_gotoxy(0, 1);
            lcd_putsf("Yes press 1");
            lcd_gotoxy(0, 2);
            lcd_putsf("No press 2");
            if (ScanKey() == 1)
            {
                PORTC .0 = 1;
                user[Code].role = false;
                lcd_gotoxy(0, 3);
                lcd_putsf("Demoted !");
                delay_ms(150);
                PORTC .0 = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                PORTC .1 = 1;
                lcd_gotoxy(0, 3);
                lcd_putsf("Cancelled !");
                delay_ms(150);
                PORTC .1 = 0;
            }
        }
        break;

    case 8:
        lcd_clear();
        lcd_putsf("DIGITAL PASS LOCK");
        lcd_gotoxy(0, 1);
        lcd_putsf("Admins & users");
        lcd_gotoxy(0, 2);
        lcd_putsf("admin can edit users");
        lcd_gotoxy(0, 3);
        lcd_putsf("Prgrmd & bld Zavosh");
        ScanKey();

    default:
        break;
    }
}

void UserPannel(int UserCode)
{
    while (checker)
    {
        lcd_clear();
        sprintf(show, "User %d", user[UserCode].username);
        lcd_puts(show);
        lcd_gotoxy(0, 1);
        lcd_putsf("chng Username prs 1");
        lcd_gotoxy(0, 2);
        lcd_putsf("chng Password prs 2");
        lcd_gotoxy(0, 3);
        lcd_putsf("Delete 3 - Logout 4");

        EditUser(ScanKey(), UserCode);
    }
}

void AdminPannel(int AdminCode)
{
    while (checker)
    {
        lcd_clear();
        sprintf(show, "%d Users", UL);
        lcd_puts(show);
        lcd_gotoxy(0, 1);
        lcd_putsf("Edit Profile prss 1");
        lcd_gotoxy(0, 2);
        lcd_putsf("Edit Users prss 2");
        lcd_gotoxy(0, 3);
        lcd_putsf("Add Users prss 3");

        switch (ScanKey())
        {
        case 1:
            UserPannel(AdminCode);
            break;

        case 2:
            lcd_clear();
            lcd_putsf("Enter Username :");
            username = ScanKey();

            for (i = 0; i < UL; i++)
            {
                if (user[i].username == username)
                {
                    checker = false;
                    lcd_clear();
                    lcd_putsf("Username 1, Pass 2");
                    lcd_gotoxy(0, 1);
                    lcd_putsf("Logout 4, Delete 3");

                    if (user[i].role)
                    {
                        lcd_gotoxy(0, 2);
                        lcd_putsf("Demote admin 7");
                        EditUser(ScanKey(), i);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lcd_gotoxy(0, 2);
                        lcd_putsf("Promote Admin 6");
                        user[i].role = true;
                        EditUser(ScanKey(), i);
                        user[i].role = true;
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
            if (checker)
            {
                PORTC .1 = 1;
                lcd_clear();
                lcd_putsf("User Not Found !!");
                delay_ms(150);
                PORTC .1 = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                checker = true;
            }
            break;

        case 3:
            EditUser(5, AdminCode);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a few clarifying comments: 1) there are only two valid signatures for the `main()` function,.  The are:  1) `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char * argv[] )`  2) You should post a [mcve] so we can reporoduce the problem so we can help you debug it.  3) C assumes everything ia an `int` unless you tell it otherwise, so all the function prototypes are missing. 4) the definition of struct "user' is missing as is the declaration of the `user[]` array  5) many of the 'global' variables are never declared (cont)

Comment: (cont) the function `ScanKey()` returns the ascii value of a single key stroke, not a string of keystrokes.  suggest reading: [AVR function library](https://exploreembedded.com/wiki/AVR_C_Library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Linker warning: function 'UserIdentify' not used in data stack usage
> calculation due to possible recursive calls

This message tells you that the compiler is unable to estimate the data stack usage of your code because it detected a possible recursive call. In case of recursive call, stack use depends on the data values at run-time so the compiler doesn't know it.